# I am unable to run the project in local environment after running the service httpd restart

Tags: php, apache, http, elgg

After running the httpd by using the command `service httpd restart`, but I am unable to run the project locally. While running the project, it displayed the PHP code. Can you please help me to solve the issue? This is the PHP code:

```
<?php// allow testing from the upgrade page before the site is upgraded.if (isset($_GET['__testing_rewrite'])) {
if (isset($_GET['__elgg_uri']) && false !== strpos($_GET['__elgg_uri'], '__testing_rewrite')) {
    echo "success";
}
exit;}require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/engine/start.php");$router = _elgg_services()->router;$request = _elgg_services()->request;if (!$router->route($request)) {
forward('', '404');}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the HTTP config and error log. The PHP module is not loaded any longer, or the .php extension (or whatever extension you've used) isn't associated with the PHP module any longer.

Until you give us more details, that's all we can answer with.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for replying my question. I checked the http config and error log file  but i didn't find any error, after restart the httpd. This is the configuration file i am using in my local. Can you please check it once.Advance thank you sir.

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName local.women.org
#       ServerAlias
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/women/
        <Directory  /var/www/html/women/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from all
                </Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/women/women_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/women/women_access_log common
</VirtualHost>

Comment: That's not the web servers config file, only the site's config. You need to check httpd.conf, and go from there. Reading up in the PHP manual on how to manually install PHP in your web server will help you a lot on the way. http://php.net/manual/en/install.php